# How to get data from json_encode using $.each?

Tags: jquery, json

How do I get the data from the data like this? http://pastebin.com/FGKgbGa7

My code :

```
function getData(){
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'process.php', 
        cache: false,
        success : function(result) {
            $.each(result, function(id, item){

            })
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception){
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500]');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.')
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.')
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.')
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

How to get `id`, `snippet`, `updated_time` etc...

Thanks

Comment: why don't you just use a for loop?

Comment: What do you mean? @Shannon

Comment: try `console.log("item", item)` inside the `.each` function (which really doesn't need to be used you can use a standard for loop instead of the jquery wrapper) to see where you are at in the object. Do you get another object that has the keys you want? If not maybe you need another loop or to root at a different level. This is a basic debugging method that will help in your issue.

Comment: @BerthoJoris A for loop is a language construct that allows code to be repeatedly executed. You should become familiar with these as you will need to use them quite often.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `.each`, a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) would suffice.

```
for (var item in result.data) {
    // do stuff with item
    console.log(item.id);
}
```

If you want to use `.each` for whatever reason, it should look like this

```
$.each(result.data, function(id, item){
    // print properties
    console.log(item.id);
});
```

because result.data is the array you want to loop through.

Comment: Using $.each `TypeError: a is undefined`, using for (...) `alert(item.id);` doesnt work

Comment: Want to add what you've done to your question? I don't see where in my code that a reference to `a` is made.

Comment: I use `$.each(data, function(id, item){ consolse.log(item[0].snippet); })` data is show, but error too

Comment: TypeError: item[0] is undefined

Comment: Item is already an object, just item.snippet will give you the snippet data. 
I can't express enough how important it is that you try to understand how loops works.

Answer (score 0):

Forget `$.each`; just do:

```
for(var key in result) {

    // whatever code
    // Example: key is id
    // result[key] is the value of id

}
```